# Convert JSON Schema Format

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I have json schema definition like this:

(**Update:** basically its draft 03 format: http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#)

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "product": {
        "name": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

But I need it in this format(standard json schema structure), which is draft 04 format(http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#)

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "product": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "name",
                "description"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "product"
    ]
}
```

Is there any converter to convert the above format to this one? I just don't want to manually do it which might be error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, so I can't vouch for it personally, but there is conversion tool.

https://github.com/geraintluff/json-schema-compatibility